# Find $x$-coordinates of all horizontal tangents on the graph of $f(x) = \sin^2x + \cos x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

The function is $f(x) = \sin^2x + \cos x$.

I found the derivative which was $f'(x) = 2x\cos^2x - \sin x$.

I think what you do next is make $f'(x) = 0$ so it becomes:

$0 = 2x\cos^2x - \sin x$.

After this, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Why $2x\cos^2(x)$?

Comment: I applied the chain rule in finding the derivative sin^2(x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake when calculating the derivative of $\sin^2(x) = (\sin(x))^2$. By the chain rule, we have $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sin(x))^2 = 2\sin(x)\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sin(x))$. If you fix the derivative, can you now solve the problem?

Comment: Okay, I see what I did wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @Macy: Have you been able to finish the problem?

Comment: I got {x:x=πn, (π/3)n,and (5π/3)n} where n is any integer.

Comment: $\pi n$, $\frac{\pi}{3}n$ and $\frac{5\pi}{3}n$ are not solutions for every integer $n$. It is true thought that $\pi$, $\frac{\pi}{3}$, and $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ are solutions (but there are more).

Comment: I'm stumped. How would I go on about finding the other solutions?

Comment: Note that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are $2\pi$-periodic. That means $\sin(x) = \sin(x + 2k\pi)$ and $\cos(x) = \cos(x+2k\pi)$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to x = 2πn, π + 2πn, (π/3) + 2nπ, and (5π/3) + 2πn.

Comment: The last three are correct, but not $x = 2\pi n$. Where did you get $x = 2\pi n$?

Comment: I thought that sinx = 0 at two places in the unit circle, at 0 (or 2π) and at π. That's how I got x=2πn.

Comment: Don't you want $\cos(x) = 0$ rather than $\sin(x)$? I've just noticed that $x = \pi +2\pi n$ do not form solutions either.

Comment: From the derivative I got, (correct me if I'm wrong) which was f'(x) = 2sinxcosx-sinx, I distributed sinx and got f'(x) = sinx(2cosx-1). So, from this I got two answers when I made this equal zero: sinx=0 and 2cosx-1=0.

Comment: Whoops. I was looking at the wrong thing, you are absolutely correct. You want $\sin(x) = 0$ which occurs when $x = n\pi$, $n$ an integer, and $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ which occurs when $x = \frac{\pi}{3} +2n\pi$ and $x = \frac{11\pi}{3} + 2n\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly performed the chain rule. The derivative is actually $2 \cos x \sin x - \sin x$. Now, in setting the derivative to zero, we try to find extrema. If the slope is undefined, the line is most likely to be vertical, and if the point has a zero slope, then it is horizontal. Keep in mind there are multiple solutions for $x$ in the following problem:

$$2 \cos x \sin x - \sin x = 0$$

Comment: "the point is most likely to be vertical" What does this mean?

Comment: Well, think about a line. If you were to graph the function $x = 3$ as a function of y, you would get a vertical line with an undefined slope. Thus, if the slope is undefined then the line is vertical at that point. If the slope is 0, however, (try graphing $y = 2$), then you get a horizontal point.

Comment: Yes, the *line* is vectical, not the point.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^2 x$ means $(\sin x)^2$, not $\sin (x^2)$
so $(\sin^2 x)' =2\sin x\cos x$